# Showing that entire analytic functions are dense in Schwartz space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

The following theorem is presented as question 15.6 in Treves (1967, 1995). $\mathscr{S}$ is the Schwartz space of functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and when one says functions on $\mathbb{C}^n$ are 'dense' in the space, one naturally has in mind their restriction to the reals.

**Theorem.** $\hspace{0.05cm}$ The entire analytic functions which belong to $\mathscr{S}$ are dense in $\mathscr{S}$.

If we use the fact that $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the set of "bump" functions, is dense in $\mathscr{S}$, it remains to prove that the analytic functions in $\mathscr{S}$ are dense in $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in the Schwartz topology.

My approach has been to design a sequence of entire analytic functions $\{f_n\}$. A bump function $f$ is the limit, in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, of a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n\}$. Let $f_n=e^{-|x|^2}p_n(x)$. Then $f_n$ belongs to $\mathscr{S}$ and can be extended as an analytic function.

It remains to show that:

(a) $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

(b) $f_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathscr{S}$.

I am unable to show (b), nor have an a priori reason to believe it should be true. My sense is that I've been working too hard, and taking a bit of a chance, in how I've approached this.  I was wondering if someone could see a simpler approach.

Comment: Let $g_n(x)=ne^{-n^2x^2}.$ Then $f*g_n$ is a real analytic function. If $f\in \mathcal{S}$ then $f*g_n$ should tend to $f$ in $\mathcal{S}.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Do I need knowledge of distributions to show $f\star g_n\rightarrow f$ for $g_n$ Schwarz analytic and $f \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$? I'm having trouble with it, as the book hasn't come on to convolutions or Fourier transforms yet. I'm happy with a solution using them, but my systematic knowledge hasn't got that far.